# How to Center a Photoslideshow

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have trouble with centering my photoslideshow....
I hope you guys could help me.

Photoslideshow in Html :

```
<div class="w3-content w3-section" style="max-width:500px">
    <img class="mySlides" src="4.jpg">
    <img class="mySlides" src="3.jpg">
    <img class="mySlides" src="2.jpg">
</div>

<script>
    var myIndex = 0;
    carousel();

    function carousel() {
        var i;
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            x[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        myIndex++;
        if (myIndex > x.length) { myIndex = 1 }
        x[myIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
        setTimeout(carousel, 2500);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Please add your style definitions for w3-content w3-section

Answer (score 0):

Here a flexbox suggestion (I used different size images just as proof they are indeed sliding):

```js
var myIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  myIndex++;
  if (myIndex > x.length) {
    myIndex = 1
  }
  x[myIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  setTimeout(carousel, 2500);
}
```

```css
.w3-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="w3-content w3-section">
  <img class="mySlides" src="https://placehold.it/100x100">
  <img class="mySlides" src="https://placehold.it/150x150">
  <img class="mySlides" src="https://placehold.it/200x200">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<style>
.w3-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `margin: auto;` and `display: block;` style For center image. see  here for display center image. http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp.

Try below css style:

```
 .w3-content img{
      display: block;
      margin:0 auto;
 }
```

**Demo**

```js
var myIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  myIndex++;
  if (myIndex > x.length) {
    myIndex = 1
  }
  x[myIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  setTimeout(carousel, 2500);
}
```

```css
.w3-content img{
  display: block;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="w3-content w3-section">
  <img class="mySlides" src="https://placehold.it/100x100">
  <img class="mySlides" src="https://placehold.it/150x150">
  <img class="mySlides" src="https://placehold.it/200x200">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try styling with 'center-class'.

```
<div class="w3-content w3-section center-class" style="max-width:500px">
  <img class="mySlides" src="4.jpg" >
  <img class="mySlides" src="3.jpg" >
  <img class="mySlides" src="2.jpg" >
</div>

<style>
  .center-class{
      display:block;
      margin-left:auto;
      margin-right:auto;
  }
</style>
```